# Easy to use booking software?

Tags: software-rec

Looking for an easy to use B&B booking software that will allow the owner to schedule and rent rooms.

It would ideally have a windows client (with cloud sync) and thinking mobile app for reminders and such. Calendar with automatic scheduling of some sort would be great too.

Anyone heard of something along these lines?

If not - any suggestions of API's or services that one could start with to roll their own solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "cloud sync"? And what kind of reminders would the mobile app give? I don't think most people will install a mobile app for a B&B just because they're staying there for a day or two.

Comment: By cloud sync I mean the ability to save state to the net - so that after a re-install of the os, I will be able to retrieve all my data. Also, mobile app is not for clients, but for the owner - to show them the calendar of when guests are coming etc...

Comment: Google Calendar almost fits the bill - the only problem with it is it's inability to "allocate" resources, like rooms. For example, I can't say "Room A" is busy from Mon-Thurs. I can only mimic it with weird things like multiple calendars, or concurrent events of different colors...

Comment: I have seen web-based hotel management apps. These should be accessible regardless of OS and also on mobile devices. I can't remember the name of the one I came across, but this would be one way to go. Otherwise, it's probably easier to find a desktop app that lets you sync with Google Calendar and just save the booking database in a Dropbox folder. Because cloud syncing doesn't seem like a particularly essential feature for booking software, so few probably implement it on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web-based solution is probably a better idea. It would work with any device that has a web browser, and so long as you have a tablet or smart phone, even if your ISP is down you can still take and manage reservations.

A Google search yields quite a few results for online hotel reservation systems: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+hotel+booking+system

Even a few Content Management Systems have reservation plugins allowing you to install the software on your own site and host for greater control and privacy: http://joomlahbs.com/